# How do I add a second working password to this code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add a second password to this code, but when I do, using the same method with the original password it gives me an error saying:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "J:\2019\digital solutions\assessment sql tkinter.py", line 22, in submit
        entry_username.delete(0,"END")
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2679, in delete
        self.tk.call(self._w, 'delete', first, last)
    _tkinter.TclError: bad entry index "END"
```

I've tried to use the same code as the original to add a second code using and 'elif' statement but i'm met with an error message, my code:

```
import tkinter
import _tkinter


from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def submit():
    password = entry_password.get()
    username = entry_username.get()
    messageAlert = Label(root,width = 30)
    messageAlert.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)




    #student log-in 

   if password != "aaaaaa":
        messageAlert.config(text = "Password incorrect")
        entry_username.delete(0,"END")
        entry_password.delete(0,"END")
        entry_username.focus_set()

   elif password != "bbbbbb":
        messageAlert.config(text = "Password incorrect")
        entry_username.delete(0,"END")
        entry_password.delete(0,"END")
        entry_username.focus_set()

   else:
        messageAlert.config(text = "Password accepted")
        print ("password accepted")
        print ("Username: ", username)
        print ("Password: ", password)
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Password Ok", message = "press Ok to continue")
        root.destroy()


def hint():
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Password hint", message = "Hint: Try password aaaaaa")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x180")
root.title("Login Screen")
root.resizable (False, False)
root.configure(background = "Light blue")


frame_entry = Frame(root)

frame_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)


frame_buttons = Frame(root)
frame_buttons.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)


Label(frame_entry, text = "Enter username: ").grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

entry_username = Entry(frame_entry, width = 15, bg = "white")
entry_username.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

Label(frame_entry, text = "Enter password: ").grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)


entry_password = Entry(frame_entry, width=15, bg = "white", show = "*")

entry_password.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

submit_button = Button(frame_buttons, text = "Submit", width = 8, command = submit)
submit_button.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)

hint_button = Button(frame_buttons, text = "password hint", width = 15, command = hint)

hint_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

root.mainloop()
print("carry on now...")
```

I expect to have two passwords that are accepted as the correct password.

Comment: you have to use `'end'` instead of `'END'`

Comment: You'll need to check your logic too as you'll never hit the `else`, eg. If `password` = "aaaaaa" then `password != "bbbbbb"` will be true instead of going into the `else` as desired.

Comment: it should be `if password  == "aaaaaa" or passwor == "bbbbbb": print ("password accepted") else: print("Password incorrect")` or  little shorter `if password  in ("aaaaaa", "bbbbbb"): print ("password accepted") else: print("Password incorrect")`

Comment: @HenryYik no, it will not, because it checks in tuple with two strings, not in string. This code alllows for `"a" `- `if password in "aaaaaa":` . And `password != ("aaaaaa" or "bbbbbb")` doesn't works as you expect. It first convert `"aaaaaa" or "bbbbbb"` to `"aaaaaa"` and then it check `if password !=  "aaaaaa"` so for `"bbbbbb" it gives `True` which is wrong result. It would have to be `password != "aaaaaa" or password != "bbbbbb"`

Comment: @furas ah now i know why. It should be `if password not in ("aaaaaa", "bbbbbb"):` instead of just in. I got confused for a second while combining your statement with poster's code.

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the exception:

> _tkinter.TclError: bad entry index "END"

You can use

```
entry_username.delete(0, END)
entry_password.delete(0, END)
```

Where END comes from tinker using the statement `from tkinter import *`

OR

```
entry_username.delete(0, "end")
entry_password.delete(0, "end")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the error:

> _tkinter.TclError: bad entry index "END"

Use `"end-1c"` or `"end"` or `END` instead of `"END"` & change code from:

```
         if password != "aaaaaa":
            messageAlert.config(text = "Password incorrect")
            entry_username.delete(0,"END")
            entry_password.delete(0,"END")
            entry_username.focus_set()
```

To:

```
         if password == "aaaaaa":
            messageAlert.config(text = "Password incorrect")
            entry_username.delete(0,END)
            entry_password.delete(0,END)
            entry_username.focus_set()
```

#### Full Code:

```
import tkinter
import _tkinter


from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def submit():
    password = entry_password.get()
    username = entry_username.get()
    messageAlert = Label(root,width = 30)
    messageAlert.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)




    #student log-in 

    if password == "aaaaaa":
         messageAlert.config(text = "Password incorrect")
         entry_username.delete(0,END)
         entry_password.delete(0,END)
         entry_username.focus_set()

    elif password == "bbbbbb":
         messageAlert.config(text = "Password incorrect")
         entry_username.delete(0,END)
         entry_password.delete(0,END)
         entry_username.focus_set()
 
    else:
         messageAlert.config(text = "Password accepted")
         print ("password accepted")
         print ("Username: ", username)
         print ("Password: ", password)
         messagebox.showinfo(title = "Password Ok", message = "press Ok to continue")
         root.destroy()


def hint():
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Password hint", message = "Hint: Try password aaaaaa")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x180")
root.title("Login Screen")
root.resizable (False, False)
root.configure(background = "Light blue")


frame_entry = Frame(root)

frame_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)


frame_buttons = Frame(root)
frame_buttons.grid(row = 2, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 10, pady = 10)


Label(frame_entry, text = "Enter username: ").grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)

entry_username = Entry(frame_entry, width = 15, bg = "white")
entry_username.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

Label(frame_entry, text = "Enter password: ").grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)


entry_password = Entry(frame_entry, width=15, bg = "white", show = "*")

entry_password.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

submit_button = Button(frame_buttons, text = "Submit", width = 8, command = submit)
submit_button.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)

hint_button = Button(frame_buttons, text = "password hint", width = 15, command = hint)

hint_button.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)

root.mainloop()
print("carry on now...")
```